# Populating Percentile Data Using a MySQL Query (Pic)

Tags: sql, mysql, security, statistics

I need to add a percentile column to this password data set of 17 million+ records. It is my understanding that the percentile is the total number of passwords with the same or higher occurrences, divided by the total number of passwords. Is this correct? How should I approach this in MySQL?

[image]

Comment: The percentage is whatever you want it to be.  Until that's determined, there's no point in providing a query.  Also, there's no percentage column -- does it have to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT ... percentage AS 100*occurrences/SUM(occurrences) ...`